# Unable to extract resolved value from async function

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I've created a function to get the current user's data from the Reddit API, as part of a `Reddit` object with multiple functions.

```js
async getCurrentUserId() {
        if (userID) return userID;

        const token = await Reddit.getAccessToken().then(val => {
            return val;
        })
        const url = "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me"
        const headers = {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            "User-Agent": "blablabla",
        };

        const response = await fetch(url, { headers: headers });
        if (response.ok) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.json();
            return jsonResponse.name;
        }
    },
```

However, when I try and extract the data, I keep getting a promise rather than the resolved value, and I can't seem to be able to figure it out.

```js
const userID = Reddit.getCurrentUserId().then(val => {
  return val;
}) // returns "Promise {<pending>}"
```

Assistance with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to do your logic inside `.then()`, or simplify by using `await`:

```js
const token = await Reddit.getAccessToken();

...

const userID = await Reddit.getCurrentUserId();
```

Comment: I can't `await` outside an `async` function, so how do I go about assigning the resolved value to `userID`?

Comment: Can't you really make the function `async`? That would be the most natural way to do this, but in the very specific case you can't then do this:

```let userID; Reddit.getCurrentUserId().then(val => { userID = val; });```

Comment: I tried that earlier and I'm able to log the resolved value to the console, but the issue I'm having is saving the resolved value to a variable that I can then pass to a React app component to display on the screen. I can't seem to be able to access the resolved value outside the promise.

Comment: If you're working with react, use an state hook (`const [userId, setUserId] = useState();`) and set the value in the `.then`: (`.then(val => { setUserId(val) } )`)

Comment: That worked; I should've known that was the solution. Thanks so much for your help!